# Use a timer as a Zoom participant

Tags: time-management, video-conferencing, meetings

I have weekly meetings on Zoom during which participants are encouraged to speak. However, some speak too long, not allowing enough time for others, so we sometimes use a timer to control how long people speak.

The low-tech solution that we currently use is that one person runs a timer app on their smartphone and then points their computer camera at this timer on their phone. The downside to this is that the time keeper cannot show themselves on video, and that they have to monitor themselves when it is their turn to speak.

I am seeking an integrated solution. The best I have found is the [Zoom app provided by BlueSky](https://marketplace.zoom.us/apps/3Jdbzv64QnKYAT911tlV9Q), which has a lovely timer app that features everything we need. I particularly like the option to send the timer as a Zoom video participant. The downside of this otherwise great solution is that -- no surprise -- it ain't free (or, it is free for only two meetings per month). I just find [$10 per month](https://blueskyapps.org/pricing) rather pricy for a timer.

[Zoom itself provides a timer app](https://marketplace.zoom.us/apps/cXw5IXmqT6SIIBQxgM_PfQ). This is free, but is a little too basic for what I would like. Specifically, it requires me to share my screen (so others cannot share their screen when the timer is being used) and there is no negative countdown when time is up (which I find useful to encourage people to wrap up quickly when they run overtime).

What I would like is a free (or very cheap) option that lets me create a Zoom participant that is in fact a desktop app. That way, I could use a desktop timer ([Hourglass](https://chris.dziemborowicz.com/apps/hourglass/) is my favourite) and send it as a Zoom participant in the meeting. This would be a general solution that can solve many other problems beyond just a simple timer.

Is there anything like this, or any other free or cheap solution that might solve my problem?

Comment: If your computer supports video virtual backgrounds you might use a video as a timer.